# Confused which div requires overflow hidden

Tags: html, css

We are designing a simple SMS list view using div containers.  The basic idea is to make this page work for different mobile screen sizes.  I do not want to load any 3rd party scripts like bootstrap.

I managed to design the page and it is available in http://jsfiddle.net/my9Lt7jf/.  It looks good but if I shrink the browser to a smaller width then the div container that holds the name and mobile number gets wrap and broken to the next line.  The same applies for the text message.  I do not want to bring that to the next line when the browser shrinks to smaller width.  Instead I want the text to be hidden with 3 dots so that it can display in a single line with 3 dots at the end.

The CSS code

```
.his_outercontainer{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid #cccccc;
  height:50px;
  display: table;
}
.his_leftcontainer{
  width:30px;
  padding:3px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.his_middlecontainer{
  padding:3px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.his_rightcontainer{
  padding:3px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align:right;
}
.his_mobilenumber{
  font-weight:bold;
}
.his_textmessage{
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-top:3px;
}
.his_senttime{
  font-style:italic;
}
.his_flagindicator{
  padding-top:3px;
}
```

HTML Code

```
    <div class='his_outercontainer'>
        <div class='his_leftcontainer'>
            <input type='checkbox' />
        </div>
        <div class='his_middlecontainer'>
            <div class='his_mobilenumber'>
                Ramkumar <+911234567890>
            </div>
            <div class='his_textmessage'>
                Happy birthday to you Mr.John
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='his_rightcontainer'>
            <div class='his_senttime'>
                31st Oct 10:45 pm
            </div>
            <div class='his_flagindicator'>
                <img src='green.png' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How it looks like is as below

[image]

But How it should be as below

[image]

Comment: Try using http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following css

```
.his_mobilenumber {
   width: 153px;  /* Give it a fixed width and set the overflow as below */
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I could see the text not breaking to the 2nd line and also 3 dots appearing.  But it requires a fixed width.  Providing fixed width will always shows the size in all screen sizes.  Consider the page is displayed in a tablet or wide screen then even though there are spaces it will show only the specified width.

Comment: yea thats true.. for that, you can use media queries, that sets the width based on screen size.. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). Sadly, to use the "overflow"css feature to trigger.. there should be a fixed width that can be overflown. Another option will be to use JS to manipulate the width

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `text-overflow: ellipsis` See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) for me info.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using:

```
    div {
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.his_mobilenumber
    {
    width: 300px; /* you can change this to your desired width */
    text-overflow: ellipsis; /* any text that overflows will be replaced with a '...' at the end'. */
    overflow: hidden; /* this will hide anything that overflows the container */
    whitespace: nowrap; /* text will never wrap to the next line */
    }
```

w3schools is a good site to use for help :)

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to do without a desired width.  Probably with a minimum width because I dont want to show the dots in a wider screen mobiles.